# change dataframe values when user inputs numericInput shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am having difficulty implementing this code on a more complicated setup that I have. My goal is to let the user change column values with the projected values rendered from numericInput button. Global.R is not an option as there are many operations placed on the dataset before the final version is reached. I have everything setup other than being able to observe the input$action and change the dataframe when an action occurs.

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(
titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),



# Create a new row for the table.
 fluidRow(
  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = unique(data$Projection), 
              selected = unique(data$Projection)[1]),
  numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = unique(data$Projection)[1]),
  submitButton(text = "Apply Changes", icon = NULL),
  dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
)    
)  
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Load the ggplot2 package which provides
# the 'mpg' dataset.

 # Given that you are not plotting this line is
### useless library(ggplot2)

# Define a server for the Shiny app

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data$User_Prediction[data$Projection==input$select] <<- input$num
    data
  })
})
```

**global.r**

```
 data <- as.data.frame(c(98,99,34))
 names(data) <- "Projection"
 data$User_Prediction <- 0
```

Data is stored in server.R as such

```
 data <-reactive({
 ...
 ...
 ...
 data
 })
```

I am trying to bring in data which is stored in the reactive function into

```
 d <- reactiveValues(dat=data)
```

I have tried

```
 d <- data()
 d <- data
 d <- reactiveValues(dat=data)
```

Is there any way I could access the data, because otherwise your code works.

Comment: put your datt in a reactiveValues, `values <- reactiveValues(dat = data)` in the server.  The make an `observeEvent(input$button, values$data[...] <- new_values)` to update it.  This is basic stuff is quite well documented at Rstudios site.

Comment: and this site, https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples, I particulary like.  It has heaps of examples.  On a side note, the way you are doing it now with `<<-` is not good.  Reactive values are passed by reference so when you use them you only need `<-` unlike normal R objects.

Comment: Thank you for the response. observeEvent is not an option at this time so I am trying to find an alternative. Do you know how I can make a dataframe global so that ui and server can access it, without setting it in global.R

Comment: put in your server as a reactive value!

Comment: if you have the data in your `reaciveValues`, say `values <- reactiveValues(dat=data)`, you can access from within a *reactive* context using `values$data`.  From outside a reactive context, you can use `d <- isolate(values$data)`, or `reactiveValuesToList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this without `observeEvent` you could do this:

```
data <- as.data.frame(c(98,99,34))
names(data) <- "Projection"
data$User_Prediction <- 0

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),



    # Create a new row for the table.
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
                         choices = unique(data$Projection), 
                         selected = unique(data$Projection)[1]),
             numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = unique(data$Projection)[1]),
             actionButton('btn',"Apply Changes"),
             dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
             )
    )    
  )  
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  d <- reactive({
    data
  })

  dat <- reactiveValues(dat=NULL)
  observe({
    dat$dat <- d()
  })

  observe({
    input$btn
    isolate({
      num <- input$num
      sel <- input$select
    })
    dat$dat$User_Prediction[dat$dat$Projection==sel] <- num
    #d2 <- dat
  })

  # Better way
#   observeEvent(input$btn,{
#     dat$dat$User_Prediction[dat$dat$Projection==sel] <- num
#   })

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    dat$dat
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: the data that I am using is in a reactive content. It doesn't work when I put d<-data( ). How could I approach it?

Comment: I update the answer so that the data is stored in a reactive list

Comment: My data comes out of data <- reactive{(.......process data... return data})        When I try d <- reactiveValues(dat=data), it doesn't work. I also tried d <- reactiveValues(dat=data( )) It says, could not find function

Comment: I edited my original post towards the bottom to be more clear. I really appreciate it.